# Is there a name for the distance from the mean in units of standard deviations?

Tags: statistics

I'm computing a `value` as follows:

```
value = (actual-mean)/standard_deviation
```

I *want* to call this the "sigma distance", but is there a [quote]real name[/quote] for it?

Comment: This is usually called the "$z$ score".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments:  This is usually called the $z$ score, or the Standard Score.  A convenient reference can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

Comment: :D Thanks. No reason to leave easy points on the table...